# How to go about making an array of the items between two keywords of another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sounds way more confusing than it actually is, but it is simple given an example:

Let's say I have an array like this - `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

I want the numbers 2, 3 and 4 in their own array like this - `[2, 3, 4]`

One detail is that the array is completely random! It is all user inputted so I use keywords to find the section I want, like this - `["cmd", "|arg", "stuff", "blah", "|end"]`

For this example I would like an array of the items between the keywords `|arg` and `|end` that looks like this - `["stuff", "blah"]`

I have already found the position in the array of the two keywords but how would I go about making an array of the items between these keywords?

I have tried splicing and I have tried `for`, but `for` is not allowed in the game I am coding for and I just cannot seem to find out how to splice it. There has to be a better way and I am not sure what the Method would be called if there even is a Method that can accomplish this.

**I don't have any real code to show, as it would be a complete and utter mess if I show it**

*Just started learning javascript 3 days ago*

Comment: You mentioned you have already foud out the indices of the nodes, you can try to splice the array with these indices right?

Comment: Have a look at `Array.slice`. It will extract a portion of the array, defined by start and end position. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you first check to see if that the array contains both values, then you can slice the array into another result array.

```js
let ar = ["cmd", "|arg", "stuff", "blah", "|end"];
let arRes = [];

if(ar.includes("|arg") && ar.includes("|end")){
  let idx1 = ar.indexOf("|arg") + 1;
  let idx2 = ar.indexOf("|end");
  arRes = ar.slice(idx1, idx2)
}

console.log(arRes)
```